# How to normalize just one feature by scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, feature-scaling

Wanna apply a specific scaler, say [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), on a specific feature, keeping other features intact.

the dataset format is something like:
[
[1, 0.2, 1000],
[2, 0.1, 2400],
[3, 0.9, 7620]
]

I need to transform only one column, the third in this example.

I don't want to use [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass one column to the scaler, and change the data inlace, something like:

```
x[i,:] = scaler.transform(x[i,:])
```

Once the scaler is fitted.

Comment: Thanks, It works only if x is numpy.array, not list. Btw, no problem, wrapping x in  numpy.array().

Comment: If it's just a list, then `x[i]` should work ;)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, the easiest way is to apply the `StandardScaler` to only the subset of features that need to be scaled, and then concatenate the result with the remaining features.

Alternatively, scikit-learn also offers (a still experimental, i.e. subject to change) `ColumnTransformer` API. It works similar to a `pipeline`:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 
from sklearn.preprocessing import  StandarScaler 
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [('scaler', StandardScaler(),2],
    remainder='passthrough') 
column_trans.fit_transform(X)
```

The third entry of the tuple (here : `2`) can be a single or a list of column indices (or column names when working with a pandas DataFrame).